# Something better than dir()?

Tags: python, directory

Python's `dir()` is nice, don't get me wrong. But I'd like a list that actually tells me what kind of things the objects are: methods, variables, things that are inherited, etc.

As best I can tell, `dir` always returns a simple list of strings with no indication as to what the objects are. I checked the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir) for `dir()` and I don't see any way of getting better information.

Are there any other packages or tools for doing this?

Comment: You're probably looking for [inspect.getmembers](https://docs.python.org/3/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#inspect.getmembers) and/or all the other methods that ``inspect`` provides.

Comment: These are both great answers. I feel like I should've known about inspect.getmembers. This is a really hard thing to search for though because of the ubiquity of "dir" as a term

Answer (score 0):

*I'd like a list that actually tells me what kind of things the objects are: methods, variables, things that are inherited, etc.*

[`pyclbr`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/pyclbr.html) built-in module might be useful for you, if you are interested in classes in certain *.py file, let `somefile.py` content be

```
class MyClass():
    def parent_method(self):
        return None

class MyChildClass(MyClass):
    def child_method(self):
        return None
```

then

```
import pyclbr
objects = pyclbr.readmodule("somefile")
print(objects['MyChildClass'].super)
print(objects['MyChildClass'].methods)
```

output

```
['MyClass']
{'child_method': 6}
```

Explanation: `pyclbr` does not execute code, but extract information from python source code. In above example from `.super` we can conclude that `MyChildClass` is child of `MyClass` and that `MyChildClass` define method `child_method` in 6th line of line